# Could not identify manufacturer of Pi TFT LCD screen

Tags: raspbian, pitft

I bought a Pi TFT LCD screen, trying to install in my rpi (OS: raspbian), i am following steps in 
http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/

But i don't know what is the brand of my lcd screen, the buyer didn't provide any installation guides, so i have to search online.

I bought from

http://www.lelong.com.my/3-2-inch-tft-lcd-touch-screen-display-monitor-raspberry-pi-b-b-zt-lee-I2490482-2007-01-Sale-I.htm

What i know about the lcd screen is:

Touch panel control chip: **XPT2046**

LCD Controller chip: **ILI9341**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work but it is what I would do if I had an unknown screen.

/boot/overlays/README contains settings for a number of Pi displays.

I would work through that list.

For each one you would need to edit /boot/config.txt to add the display overlay and then reboot.  If the display doesn't work then remove the added entry before trying the next.

E.g. for the hy28a display add the following line in /boot/config.txt and reboot.

dtoverlay=hy28a

---

Edited to add

Alternatively see if you can find a match for the LCD driver and touch screen driver at https://github.com/notro/fbtft

Comment: tried dtoverlay=<diff name>, it don't work.

Comment: @user3172596 Perhaps look at https://github.com/notro/fbtft